# Reading a value of an array in a struct into the next indexed value?

Tags: c

**I'm trying to get the line:**

allTowns[i - 1].startTown = allTowns[i].endTown;

**to work, but whenever i run it i get an error code stating**

"Error: Assignment to expression with array type"

**Does anyone know why this is? My end goal is to run through the file energy.txt and put its contents into the array allTowns[1024], i got this to work, but now i would like to make every second line the same as the previous but with startTown, endTown swapped.**

**e.g. a file that looks like this:**

Hull York 30

Manchester Derby -21

**would create a struct i can print that looks like this:**

Hull York 30

York Hull 30

Manchester Derby -21

Derby Manchester -21

**Thank you very much for any help anyone can provide or suggestions, i'm new to C, the code I've pasted below is my code, but I have missed off the includes (<stdio.lib> and <stdio.h>). as it is in a header file**

```
struct intertownEnergy {
  char startTown[256];
  char endTown[256];
  int energyExpended;

}
allTowns[1024], reverseTowns[1024], readInTowns[8];

int openEnergyFile(void) {
  FILE * energyFilePtr = fopen("energy.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  if (energyFilePtr == NULL) {
    printf("the file doesn't exist");
    return 0;
  }

  while (!feof(energyFilePtr)) {
    fscanf(energyFilePtr, "%s %s %d\n", & allTowns[i].startTown, & allTowns[i].endTown, & 
allTowns[i].energyExpended);
    printf("Printing the file: %s %s %d\n", & allTowns[i].startTown, & allTowns[i].endTown, 
allTowns[i].energyExpended);
    i++;
    allTowns[i - 1].startTown = allTowns[i].endTown;
  }
  printf("\n");
  //printf("Printing town middle test: %s %s %d\n", &allTowns[19].startTown, &allTowns[12].endTown, allTowns[12].energyExpended); WORKING TEST

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C you can't copy a string by using `=` but you can use `strcpy()` such as with `strcpy(allTowns[i - 1].startTown, allTowns[i].endTown);`

Comment: Aside: please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) better to control the loop with `while(fscanf(energyFilePtr, "%s %s %d", ... ) == 3)` note that I removed the incorrect newline from the format string too.

Comment: Thank you for the help! that's solved my problem, i replaced the !feof as well, is there a way i can upvote you or your reply as a thank you?

Comment: Re my second point: you may have found that you process the last line in your input *twice*.

Comment: You *did* thank me, keep coming back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, an array is a starting address and a size in memory.

When you write like this you have two different arrays in memory and you are trying to move the contents of one to the other.

```
allTowns[i - 1].startTown = allTowns[i].endTown;
```

This is not allowed in C, at least not with that syntax.

Instead you need to copy the *contents* of endTown to startTown, this can be done with strncpy or memcpy

```
memcpy(allTowns[i - 1].startTown, allTowns[i].endTown,sizeof(allTowns[i - 1].startTown))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy arrays with `=`. `strncpy` works.

```
 strncpy(allTowns[i - 1].startTown, allTowns[i].endTown, 255)[255] = 0;
```

Here the string is 255 characters long and we use the last spot only for the null terminator.

There really should be a dupe for this but I failed to find it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out before you should use strcpy() function in <string.h> library.

**The reason however**, because strings in C are **pointers**, more specifically, they point to the address of the first character of the string. Using (=) operator means that you are assigning the address of `allTowns[i].endTown` to this pointer `allTowns[i - 1].startTown` which is not allowed since it's almost similar to doing this `allTowns[i].endTown = 0x7ffff3a9ae94`, b/c it is the operating system's job to assign memory addresses to pointers.